# Deactivate Appcompat on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, overflow-menu

I moved from using Eclipse to use Android Studio, but I foun with a problem, AppCompat is bringing me some problems and I don't want to use it so I tried to deactivated but I didn't find a way. There is an option in Android Studio to deactivate it? Because manually adapting the project (changing inherations, prefixes and themes) after it has been built takes a lot of time.

The problem is that when using the AppCompat, I can't create an Overflow menu. If I write "app:ifRom" the item appears on the ActionBar, that's right. But if I write "app:never" the overflow icon (3 dots) never appear, and if I touch the hardware key for opening the overflow menu, the app suddenly stops. That is why I do't want to use the AppCompat, because without using it (using the android: prefixes instead of app: prefixes) I didn't have any problem.

If you could help me solving one of this questions: How to deactivate AppCompat on Android Studio or why the "app:never" prefix is not working I would be gratefull.

Comment: I'd rather solve the issue why it doesn't work. Can you please post your menu layout file?

Comment: Just remove below in build.gradle file.
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'
}

Comment: Worked removing the dependencie from build.gradle file. Thank you.